# counting lines in http logs, global line number not updated

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to use scala/spark to parse http log files (488 files in one directory)

```
scala> val logs2 = sc.textFile("D:/temp/tests/wwwlogs")
logs2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = D:/temp/tests/wwwlogs  
     MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> logs2.count
res1: Long = 230712

scala> logs2.filter(l => l.contains("92.50.64.234")).count()
res2: Long = 47
```

then I manually edit one file an add the following line:

> 2017-12-31 03:48:32 *.*.*.* GET /status full=true 80 - 92.50.64.234 Python-urllib/2.7 - 404 0 2 416

```
scala> logs2.filter(l => l.contains("92.50.64.234")).count()
res3: Long = 48
```

great but then I execute again

```
scala> logs2.count
res4: Long = 230712
```

That is the same number of lines when I expect 230712 + 1 as I add one line to a file.

Why the filter result is updated but the global count is not ?

Comment: It probably caches the count. Try recreating the rdd after you modify the file.

Comment: It definitely appears to cache some underlying info. If I delete some lines from a file, the count will update and I find that strange if my caching assumption is right.

Comment: @Dima if I recreate the rdd it is allright, but my confusion comes from the fact that I do not need tro recreate de rdd for filter

Comment: Well, for `filter` it would have to cache the entire result, that's impractical.

Answer (score 0):

RDD enable cache already? as for filter, maybe not apply cache.